# Trying to split a string using strtok

Tags: c

I am trying extract only "Hello World" and store it in a string. I want to ignore the first "p  ". For example, I just want to print out "Hello World" using strtok. **I want to remove the first word and the space character afterwards**. How would I do that?

```
int main()
{
    char string[50] = "p Hello world";

}
```

Comment: Be more specific.  Do you want to ignore every `p` in the string?  Or only if they begin the string?  Or only if they are not adjacent to any other letters?  Your question is very ambiguous.  Fix it so that there is only one interpretation.

Comment: strtok is obsoleted by strsep(3).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: As far as I can tell, `strsep` is not part of the ISO C standard. Therefore, it cannot render a function obsolete that is part of the ISO C standard, such as `strtok`.

Comment: Simplest for your circumstance `strchr (string, ' ') + 1` to obtain a pointer to `'H'` in `"Hello world"`. You can print it `puts (strchr (string, ' ') + 1)` or copy to a new string, e.g. `strcpy (string2, strchr (string, ' ') + 1)` (and `strchr` will work on constant strings)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not entirely.  From the Linux man page for strsep:  The  strsep()  function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3), since the latter cannot handle empty fields.  However, strtok(3)  conforms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

First I take out the "p " and then I take out "Hello World". Thank you guys.

```
int main()
{
    char string[50] = "p Hello world";
    // Extract the first token
    char *first = strtok(string, " \n");

    // Now extracting hello world only
    char *second = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    printf("%s\n", second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to try `puts (strchr (string, ' ') + 1);` as an alternative. (that would replace everything between `char string[50] = "p Hello world";` and `return 0;` and would work if you declared `char *string  = "p Hello world";`)